# CrudRepository.save() игнорирует FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Для работы с БД в приложении используется Spring Data. Имеется две сущности. `Film`:

```
//аннотации опущены
public class Film {

    // другие аннотации опущены
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users;
}
```

И `User`:

```
//аннотации опущены
public class User {

    // другие аннотации опущены
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Film> films;
}
```

Они связаны отношением `ManyToMany`. Причём для Film список User загружается **EAGER**. Теперь я хочу сохранить новый объект Film в репозиторий:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudFilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Integer> {
}
```

При вызове `CrudFilmRepository#save` мне возвращается новосозданный Film, причём ещё и с id. Здесь всё работает без нареканий.

---

Теперь я создал новый класс `FilmTo`. Он будет содержать в себе не `List<User> users`, а `List<Integer> userIds`, благодаря чему с представления надо будет передавать меньше данных. Разумеется, я не могу передать в `CrudFilmRepository#save` объект FilmTo, потому что репозиторий не поймёт, что это за объект. Поэтому я делаю промежуточный метод, который получает из объекта FilmTo объект Film:

```
private Film getFromTo(FilmTo film) {
    return new Film(
        Arrays.stream(film.getUserIds())
                .map(crudUserRepository::getOne)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

План действий такой:

1. В сервис приходит объект FilmTo, содержащий не список пользователей, а список их айдишников.
2. В методе `getFromTo()` из объекта FilmTo получаем Film. **Важно!** Нам надо из списка айдишников получить список пользователей. Для лучшего перфоманса я вытаскиваю из `crudUserRepository` не целые объекты User, а **ссылки** на них *(метод getOne)*.
3. Сохраняем полученный объект Film в репозиторий.

---

**ПРОБЛЕМА:**

При передаче в `CrudFilmRepository#save` объекта Film, полученного из FilmTo при помощи метода `getFromTo()`, возвращается объект Film с новым id, но при этом список `List<User> users` в нём при итерации возвращает `LazyInitializationException`, то есть этот список инициализируется прокси-объектами,  а должен инициализироваться реальными объектами, потому что поле `users` в Film отмечен как **EAGER**.

Почему при передаче в `CrudFilmRepository#save` объекта с полями, инициализированными при помощи `getOne()`, возвращается объект с полями, так же проинициализированными не реальными объектами, а прокси-обёртками? Почему **EAGER** в данном случае не имеет силы и как это исправить?

Comment: Почему, кстати, не используете `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon указываю. Но для вопроса я убрал всё лишнее, чтобы не отвлекало, оставил только суть. Там написано "другие аннотации опущены", из ManyToMany я тоже лишнее убрал.

Comment: см. javadoc - метод getOne(ID id) возвращает прокси с инициализированным id и только. Чтобы получить сущность нужно использовать findById

Comment: @RuslanP. так а почему это играет роль? При помощи getOne() я инициализирую поля объекта. А потом этот объект сохраняю при помощи save(T entity). Этот метод же должен возвращать новую сущность по сути? А он только id обновляет, а все остальные поля так и остаются lazy.

Comment: А, моя ошибка. Но  save не должен возвращать перечитанную из БД сущность, только декларируется, что она может (а может и нет) полностью измениться.

Comment: @RuslanP. где я могу почитать про это? Правильно я понимаю, что save() не обязательно возвращает сущность прямо из бд, а может только обновить переданную сущность? По тому что ощущение именно такое, но подтверждение свои словам я так и не нашёл.

Comment: я сейчас просто смотрел исходник org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository :: save предположив, что здесь он применим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я получил верный ответ на `en.so`, причём от разработчика Hibernate *(да, я проверил, это вроде бы правда)*. Вот как он звучит:

> save() просто делегирует EntityManager.persist или EntityManager.merge и
> возвращает объект, возвращенный EntityManager.merge или переданный
> вами. Здесь FetchType не играет роли. Если вы хотите, чтобы ассоциация
> загружалась, вы можете использовать refresh или findOne.

И да, я провёл тщательный дебаг, чтобы выяснить, что происходит в методе `JpaRepository#save()`. Лично для меня это не то что было откровением, но дало некоторое представление.

Когда мы создаём репозиторий, используя `Spring DataJPA`, то в нём нет никаких методов:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudFilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Integer> {
}
```

то есть Spring должен сам инициализировать его подходящим классом. И в моём случае для этого использовался класс **SimpleJpaRepository**.

вызов `CrudFilmRepository#save` по сути является вызовом `SimpleJpaRepository#save`, который выглядит так:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Ну и всё в принципе становится более-менее понятно. К моему огромному сожалению я так и не смог найти способ посмотреть, как выглядит `persist()` под капотом. Но как минимум `persist()` декларируется просто как метод, который, насколько я понимаю, загружает сущность в контекст персистентности. Нигде не декларируется, что этот метод должен инициализировать прокси в полях сохраняемого объекта реальными объектами. Для этого может служить `refresh()`.

Ну и вроде бы получается, что **FetchType.EAGER** относится только к методам получения объекта из базы, но не к методам сохранения, поэтому он и игнорировался. Единственное, что я ещё хочу - это посмотреть на `persist()` под капотом.

---

Вообще странно, что мне никто не указал на основополагающую проблему в моей архитектуре, которую я сам заметил не так давно и которая является причиной проблемы, которую я пытался решить в этом вопросе.

Для сохранения нового объекта Film, я заполнил его поле `List<User>users` ссылками, полученными при помощи `getOne()`. Зачем я так сделал? Чтобы сэкономить обращения к базе, потому что `getOne()` не обращается к базе. Но если я ожидал, что `FetchType.EAGER` сработает и метод `save()` вернёт мне `Film` с нормально пронициализированными полями, то это всё равно бы вызвало обращение к базе данных!

В таком случае было бы минимум два запроса:

1. Сохранение `Film` в базу данных.
2. Загрузка содержимого `List<User>users` из базы данных.

И поэтому, если для меня имеет значение, что будет возвращать `CrudFilmRepository#save`, то мне не следует использовать для инициализации `getOne()`. Я в любом случае не смогу избежать лишнего обращения к базе, если буду передавать с фронта `FilmTo`, а не `Film`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо реализовать интерфейс `Persistable`

Судя по этой [статье](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/526030/)

Точка принятия решения находится в классе

```
org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate
метод: public <T> T save(T instance)
```

вот фрагмент этого метода:

```
Function<T, MutableAggregateChange<T>> changeCreator = 
persistentEntity.isNew(instance) ? this::createInsertChange : this::createUpdateChange;

return store(instance, changeCreator, persistentEntity);
```

Вся суть находится в `persistentEntity`.

Заглянем в `persistentEntity.isNew`, там увидим:

```
public boolean isNew(Object bean) {
        this.verifyBeanType(bean);
        return ((IsNewStrategy)this.isNewStrategy.get()).isNew(bean);
}
```

Получается, что есть некая «стратегия», которая и определяет, новый объект или нет.
Вопрос сводится к изучению, что это такое.

**Обратимся к определению стратегии**

Это конструктор класса: `org.springframework.data.mapping.model`.

Вот фрагмент:

```
this.isNewStrategy = Lazy.of(() -> 
Persistable.class.isAssignableFrom(information.getType()) 
        ? PersistableIsNewStrategy.INSTANCE
        : getFallbackIsNewStrategy());
```

**Что тут происходит?**

Если сохраняемый объект имплементирует интерфейс `Persistable`, то используется соответствующая стратегия (об этом мы еще поговорим), если нет, то работает логика, представленная в методе `getFallbackIsNewStrategy`. Давайте на этом моменте остановимся подробнее.

Немного пройдем по цепочке вызовов `getFallbackIsNewStrategy` и окажемся в методе

```
public boolean isNew(Object entity) класса PersistentEntityIsNewStrategy.
```

В этом методе и определяется – новый объект или нет.
Для этого берется значение поля, отмеченного аннотацией Id.

- Если значение null – значит объект новый.
- Если не null, то возможно варианты.
- Если это не примитивный тип данных, значит все понятно – это объект не новый.
- Если тип данных примитивный, то он по определению не может быть null, и выполняется проверка на 0.

Еще раз сформулируем работу этой стратегии.

- Берем значение поля Id
- Если null – объект новый
- Иначе, если не примитивный тип, значит – объект не новый.
- Если примитивный тип и значение 0, то новый, иначе не новый.

Получается, все довольно просто и логично. У нового объекта идентификатора нет, поэтому он и новый. Значение ключевого поля формируется на стороне базы данных и возвращается вместе с сохраненным объектом.

А что делать, если по каким-то причинам Id-шник надо сформировать в java-коде и передать в базу данных. В этом случае даже в новом объекте поле идентификатора будет заполнено и описанная выше стратегия уже не сработает.

**Что делать в этой ситуации?**

Использовать вторую стратегию, основанную на интерфейсе Persistable.

У этого интерфейса есть два метода `getId` и `isNew`.

Чтобы воспользоваться этим механизмом надо у объекта, который мы хотим сохранить, имплементировать этот интерфейс и самостоятельно определить, когда объект новый, а когда нет.

При выполнении кода:

```
this.isNewStrategy = Lazy.of(() -> 
Persistable.class.isAssignableFrom(information.getType()) 
        ? PersistableIsNewStrategy.INSTANCE
        : getFallbackIsNewStrategy());
```

Spring определит, что сохраняемый объект имплементирует интерфейс `Persistable` и вызовет метод `isNew`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он к сожалению не даёт ответ на мой вопрос. Интерфейс Persistable уже реализован... У меня нет проблем непосредственно с сохранением сущности. Проблема в том, что когда я сохраняю сущность, у которой поля проинициализированы ссылками, то save возвращает объект, у которого поля всё также проиницализированы ссылками, хотя они отмечены как FetchType.EAGER